# An item with the same key has already been added Issue on adding gridvalues to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i want to insert gridview values to database.When i try to insert values it throws error "An item with the same key has already been added.".Only the first row is added to database remaining rows is not getting added.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  string Check=string.Empty;
            string BranchID = dpbranch.SelectedValue;
            string ClassID = dpClassName.SelectedValue;
            string SectionID = dpsection.SelectedValue;
            TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient Attendance = new TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient();
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> AssignStudentAttendance = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdstudentattendance.Rows)
            {
                String cellText = row.Cells[0].Text;
                String RegisterNo = row.Cells[2].Text;
                int rowIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < gdstudentattendance.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //extract the TextBox values
                    CheckBox StudentAttendance = (CheckBox)gdstudentattendance.Rows[i].Cells[i].FindControl("chkattendance");
                  if(StudentAttendance.Checked==true)
                  {
                      Check="true";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       Check="false";
                  }
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("BranchID", BranchID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("ClassID", ClassID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("SectionID", SectionID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("StudentID", cellText.ToString());
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("RegisterNo", RegisterNo.ToString());
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("Attendance", Check.ToString());
                    Attendance.InsertStudentAttendance(AssignStudentAttendance);

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create new Dictionary for each row. Like:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  string Check=string.Empty;
            string BranchID = dpbranch.SelectedValue;
            string ClassID = dpClassName.SelectedValue;
            string SectionID = dpsection.SelectedValue;
            TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient Attendance = new TestSchool.SchoolBusinessLyr.SchoolBizClient();
            System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> AssignStudentAttendance;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdstudentattendance.Rows)
            {
                //Create new dictionary for each row
                AssignStudentAttendance = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();

                String cellText = row.Cells[0].Text;
                String RegisterNo = row.Cells[2].Text;
                int rowIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < gdstudentattendance.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    //extract the TextBox values
                    CheckBox StudentAttendance = (CheckBox)gdstudentattendance.Rows[i].Cells[i].FindControl("chkattendance");
                  if(StudentAttendance.Checked==true)
                  {
                      Check="true";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                       Check="false";
                  }
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("BranchID", BranchID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("ClassID", ClassID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("SectionID", SectionID);
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("StudentID", cellText.ToString());
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("RegisterNo", RegisterNo.ToString());
                    AssignStudentAttendance.Add("Attendance", Check.ToString());
                    Attendance.InsertStudentAttendance(AssignStudentAttendance);

                }
            }

        }
```